# Extract .mbtiles file in google map

Tags: php, google-maps, mbtiles

In my google map project i am using opendata ordnance survey  tiles image .
we have buy the all zoom level  tiles image.
when we purchase we can get a ".mbtiles" extension file.
I want to extract this file in my project folder , 
How can i do it , please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to pull individual image files out of an MBTiles database.